# How to run karate test in command line?

Tags: karate

I created my project with archtype found in documentation. However, it is not possible to run the test in command line. All tests are being ignored. I am running it with `mvn test` and even if I specify `mvn test -Dtest=SystemTestsRunner` it gives me an exception that no tests are found.

```
@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})
public class SystemTestsRunner {

    @Karate.Test
    Karate testAll() {
        return new Karate().relativeTo(getClass());
    }

}
```

Created with:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.intuit.karate \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=karate-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=0.9.4 \
-DgroupId=com.mycompany \
-DartifactId=myproject
```

Comment: @peter-thomas Is it possible to run Karate tests using the CLI without JDK and Maven installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your maven version is not the latest. The solution is detailed here, and will be improved in the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/823

Answer (score 0):

If you have latest maven version, you can simply execute your test cases using maven command as provided below:

```
mvn clean test -Dkarate.env=uat "-Dkarate.options=--tags @tags"
```